# How do we express the hexidecimal numbers inside the computer system in java program?

Tags: java, hex

If the sentence

```
int a  = -10000;
```

is ran on Java, what bit pattern does the variable `a` get inside the computer system if we express it with hexadecimal numbers?

Is it `0xFFFFD8F0`  or  just `FFFFD8F0`?

Comment: Those are just different representations. Like asking if it's `ffffd8f0` or `FFFFD8F0`.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking a hexadecimal number is just FFFFD8F0. The 0x prefix is one of several conventions that makes it distinguishable from a decimal number when this isn't clear from context.

If your question is how to express it in a Java program, it needs to have 0x prefix: `0xFFFFD8F0`.

Comment: Oh, then it is okay to see that even though strictly speaking FFFFD8F0 is the correct one, 0xFFFFD8F0 can be also right?

Comment: What's the context of your question? In a broad sense yes, but again it is rather a `0x` prefix followed by a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Yes, my question is mainly about how to express it in a Java program. What I'm also curious about is the expressing it 'inside the computer system' part. My classmates said that because the problem is about the variable 'a' being expressed with hexadecimal numbers 'inside the computer system', it is right to express it like FFFFD8F0, without the 0x prefix.

Comment: Inside the computer you don't have hexadecimal numbers, you have binary bits.